# Cannot add foreign key constraint (GUID)

Tags: mysql, sql

I developing a synchronization module in `vb.net`, so for avoid duplicate `id` on different record I'm using the `GUID`. Now what I'm trying to do is set the GUID as `primary key (PK)` on my table. This is the structure of the two table:

**USERS**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `GUID` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_number` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text,
  `id_roles` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastUpdated` varchar(36),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_roles` (`id_roles`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=85 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**USER_SETTINGS**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_settings` (
  `id_users` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `GUID` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `working_plan` text,
  `notifications` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `google_sync` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `google_token` text,
  `google_calendar` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sync_past_days` int(11) DEFAULT '5',
  `sync_future_days` int(11) DEFAULT '5',
  `lastUpdated` varchar(36),
  PRIMARY KEY (`GUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How you can see I've set the `FK` as GUID field in `user_settings` table, the GUID is taken from the `users` table by this:

```
ALTER TABLE `user_settings`
ADD CONSTRAINT `user_settings_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`GUID`) REFERENCES `users` (`GUID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

But I ge this error message:

> 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

What I did wrong?

Comment: You don't have an index on the keys. Duplicate question.

Comment: index? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: "How you can see I've set the PK as GUID field in user_settings table" - No, you tried to add the FK but not the PK.

Comment: Yes I wrong to type, anyway, I want use the GUID PK of user_settings reference to the GUID of users table. I edited the wrong typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent field (field in users) needs to be the primary key. You have the GUID field in the user_settings table defined as primary key. That doesnt make sense. You should have the GUID in the users as primary key, in the user_settings as simple field. Then the relationship works. Or you create an ID field in user_settings and use the 2 id fields to create the foreign key constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `GUID` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_number` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text,
  `id_roles` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastUpdated` varchar(36),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_roles` (`id_roles`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=85 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_settings` (
  `id_users` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `GUID` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `working_plan` text,
  `notifications` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `google_sync` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `google_token` text,
  `google_calendar` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sync_past_days` int(11) DEFAULT '5',
  `sync_future_days` int(11) DEFAULT '5',
  `lastUpdated` varchar(36),
  PRIMARY KEY (`GUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `user_settings`
ADD CONSTRAINT `user_settings_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

With this example all user_settings for a user will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use one column i.e. 'GUID' of user_setting table as primary key as well as foreign key. You can't use same column as PK and FK.

A Primary Key is used to enforce uniqueness within a table, and be a unique identifier for a certain record.

A Foreign Key is used for referential integrity, to make sure that a value exists in another table.

The Foreign key needs to reference the primary key in another table.

If you want to have a foreign key that is also unique, you could make a FK constraint and add a unique index/constraint to that same field.

Instead make 'id_users' column a primary key and 'GUID' column a foreign key of 'user_setting' table. And make 'GUID' column of 'users' table a primary key. Then, it will work fine.